# Maximum Connections in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, wmi

I used to find out "Maximum Connections" allowed in SQL Server 2008 by using `select @@MAX_CONNECTIONS` with the help of power-shell.

Is it possible to find the "Maximum Connections" allowed in SQL Server 2012, by using any WMI command?  I have gone through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030(v=sql.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179874(v=sql.110).aspx, but didn't helped.

Update :

```
SELECT counter_name,cntr_value FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
 WHERE [counter_name] = 'Stolen Server Memory (KB)'
```

Does anyone know, how the above command can be executed in WMI Explorer?

Comment: `SELECT @@MAX_CONNECTIONS` still works on 2012, is there a reason you can't keep on using that? FWIW, SQL Server isn't a heavy user of WMI, WMI is better for components of Windows than other software that runs on top, even Microsoft software.

Comment: Yeah, I do execute that in SQL server 2012 too, But I wanted it in WMI....... Isn't it really possible?

Comment: There is a SQL Server WMI provider which does expose network settings, but I couldn't find anything referring to Maximum Connections: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186497(v=sql.130).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will look into...

Comment: *Why* do you care about the maximum connections? This smells like client-side connection leaks. 32K connections are enough to handle millions of clients. Keeping a connection longer than needed is a very serious bug. Connection pooling also means that it doesn't cost anything to open/close connections

Comment: I was working with some monitoring features of SQl server

Comment: AFAIK, WMI is just an SDK. You have to use it with some other language or tool such as VBScript. So... right now what language are you using to call / sink WMI events? You just use that same language to call that query directly and don't bother with WMI